# Spring Boot security not bypassing login page URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using OAuth2 for security token but for few URLs like  `/login` and  `/welcome` I don't want it's access via OAuth2 token. I am using below code but for both `/login` and `/welcome` it is asking token and returning HTTP status 401.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http
             .authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                 .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
                 .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/welcome").permitAll()
                 .anyRequest().authenticated();
     }
}
```

Comment: You didnt configure OAuth2 in your configuration, so OAuth2 is never used for any URL. You get 401, because you never logged in.

Comment: Can you share the log from your IDE/server?

Comment: when i am hitting this url localhost:9094/ccp/welcome

getting this response 
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}

Complete Log:

Comment: my Oauth2 Configuration is working when i am calling API with valid Oauth2 Token i am getting the proper response